# Error when using dplyr for computing percentiles, by row

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, percentile

I have done this for an other dataset, but it is not working this time. Here is an example of my dataset:

```
ano   cbo media_var_log_salarios
  <dbl> <dbl>                  <dbl>
1  1996    20                 0.0307
2  1996    21                 0.0169
3  1996    30                 0.0141
4  1996    32                 0.0195
5  1996    33                 0.0163
6  1996    34                 0.0239
```

I want do calculate the percentiles, by "cbo". So, my code is:

```
library(dplyr)

salarios_96_01 = mutate(salarios_96_01, percentile_rank = ntile(salarios_96_01$cbo,100))
```

However, I got his error:

```
Error: Column `percentile_rank` must be length 312 (the group size) or one, not 1578
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try `mutate(salarios_96_01, percentile_rank = ntile(cbo,100))`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, @stefan!